# Как блокировать движение курсора при up и down в input?

Tags: javascript

Когда есть фокус у input и введен текст. То при нажатии кнопок up и down курсор перемещается в начало или конец строки. Как это можно предотвратить? Добавляю при событии keyup stopPropagation и preventDefault.

```
    $(me.inputSelector).on('keyup', function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 38) { // вверх 
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) { // вниз 
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: А вы уверенны что e.KeyCode вы верно написали ?? Page Up - 33 Page Down - 34

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду стрелки up и down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо повеситься на keydown:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<input value='1234567890' />
```

В момент события keyup нажатие уже обработано браузером